# Material UI React Table onCellClick not working on TableRow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have material UI Table in my react component. I want to add onCellClick event to each of the row of my table. But when I add onCellClick to each TableRow then it doesn't get fired. But when I add it to my Table Tag then it get's fired. The problem with this is when I add it to Table tag the only one type of action can be taken for all the rows. What if I want to do different things with each row whenever I click them. That's why I want to have all the TableRow tags their own onClick type of event. How can I do this?

Here is my code with onCellClick event on Table Tag, which I don't want.

```
class TagDetailTable extends Component {
        handleButtonClick() {
            browserHistory.push("TagList")
        }

        handleCellClick(){
            console.log("cell clicked")
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div>
                    <Table onCellClick= {this.handleCellClick}>
                        <TableHeader>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
                                <TableHeaderColumn>Type</TableHeaderColumn>
                                <TableHeaderColumn>Category</TableHeaderColumn>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHeader>
                        <TableBody>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>Cigarette</TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>Compliance</TableRowColumn>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow >
                                <TableRowColumn>2</TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>Cigarette</TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>Compliance</TableRowColumn>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow >
                                <TableRowColumn>3</TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>Cigarette</TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>Compliance</TableRowColumn>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow >
                                <TableRowColumn>4</TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>Alcohol</TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>Compliance</TableRowColumn>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow >
                                <TableRowColumn>5</TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>Alcohol</TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>Compliance</TableRowColumn>
                            </TableRow>
                            {/*<TableRow>*/}
                                {/*<TableRowColumn>4</TableRowColumn>*/}
                                {/*<TableRowColumn>Alcohol</TableRowColumn>*/}
                                {/*<TableRowColumn>Compliance</TableRowColumn>*/}
                            {/*</TableRow>*/}
                            {/*<TableRow>*/}
                                {/*<TableRowColumn>4</TableRowColumn>*/}
                                {/*<TableRowColumn>Alcohol</TableRowColumn>*/}
                                {/*<TableRowColumn>Compliance</TableRowColumn>*/}
                            {/*</TableRow>*/}
                            {/*<TableRow>*/}
                                {/*<TableRowColumn>4</TableRowColumn>*/}
                                {/*<TableRowColumn>Alcohol</TableRowColumn>*/}
                                {/*<TableRowColumn>Compliance</TableRowColumn>*/}
                            {/*</TableRow>*/}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                    <div className="backButton">
                        <RaisedButton backgroundColor="#293C8E" label="Back" onClick={this.handleButtonClick}
                                      labelColor="white">

                        </RaisedButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </MuiThemeProvider>

            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attaching OnCellClick to Row is not supported. See https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/2819 for more details.

However, you could use the function parameter of the handleCellClick. The signature of the function receiving the event is:

```
handleCellClick(row,column,event)
{
    if(row ==0)
       console.log('Cigarette row clicked');

}
```

Comment: How do it get which row i clicked, in this function?

Comment: You will get row index as parameter, you can use that to do the processing accordingly...

Comment: I am not getting it. Could you please tell me what should I put in this method

Comment: Are you going to use static data into your table as shown above? or will you use dynamic props? I have made edits to my answer for the case of static data.

Comment: I am going to use dynamic props.

Comment: in that case, you can use the row index to find the row from your input props. for example props.data[row]

Answer (score 20):

For those looking for this at the end of 2019, this did not work for me.
At the moment you can just put onClick on TableCell or TableRow
e.g.

```
<TableCell
  key={column.id}
  align={column.align}
  onClick={() => handleClick(row.id)}
>
```

Comment: I don't think thats the best idea. All our tabular data is rendered with TableCell and onClick event just triggers event on all the cells that mean the entire row you can say...

Answer (score 1):

```
export interface TableRowProps {
        // <tr/> is element that get the 'other' properties
        className?: string;
        displayBorder?: boolean;
        hoverable?: boolean;
        hovered?: boolean;
        /** @deprecated Instead, use event handler on Table */
        onCellClick?(e: React.MouseEvent<{}>, row: number, column: number): void;
        /** @deprecated Instead, use event handler on Table */
        onCellHover?(e: React.MouseEvent<{}>, row: number, column: number): void;
        /** @deprecated Instead, use event handler on Table */
        onCellHoverExit?(e: React.MouseEvent<{}>, row: number, column: number): void;
        /** @deprecated Instead, use event handler on Table */
        onRowClick?(e: React.MouseEvent<{}>, row: number): void;
        /** @deprecated Instead, use event handler on Table */
        onRowHover?(e: React.MouseEvent<{}>, row: number): void;
        /** @deprecated Instead, use event handler on Table */
        onRowHoverExit?(e: React.MouseEvent<{}>, row: number): void;
        rowNumber?: number;
        selectable?: boolean;
        selected?: boolean;
        striped?: boolean;
        style?: React.CSSProperties;
    }
export class TableRow extends React.Component<TableRowProps> {
    }
```

There is an `onRowClick` function which I used on `<TableRow/>` rather than defining handlers on Table itself. It's deprecated though so the solution may not be reliable. I've used material-ui v0.20 so not sure if it still works but you can give it a try.